# Java how to catch key combos on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

What would be the good way to catch combinations of keys on in JFrame, it is quite messy when using only key listener, is there any framework/library that handles this in a convenient configurable way?

Comment: Have you looked at the `KeyStroke` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for key bindings. As blackcompe says, it uses the `KeyStroke` class. 
[Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: +1, Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings, NOT KeyEvents. To catch KeyStrokes at the frame level the bindings would be added to the root pane of the frame.